# Getting Most Recent of each type in a GROUP BY

Tags: django

I'm grabbing a list of objects grouped by a foreign key's name. I use the `values` method to do this:

```
Reading.objects.values('type__name', 'value')
```

The problem with this statement is that it returns EVERY value for a given type name. So say I have a type with the name `air`, if there are 10 readings for air, I get 10 dictionaries back with various values.

I'm only interested in the most recent of these values. Is there any way to tell Django to still run a GROUP BY like statement, but only give me the most recent entry for each group?

Comment: have you tried using .annotate(Count('field_name')) ?

Comment: not sure why that would help in any way. I essentially need to load only the most recent item into memory for each type.

Comment: values doesn't group by data . its does select col1, colm2 . Maybe this is what you are looking for. Assuming modified_date is how u find the most recent .
Reading.objects.values('type__name', 'value').annotate(Count('type__name')).order_by("-modified_date")

Comment: That takes care of the ordering, but it still has the problem of returning the data for all of the values, not just the most recent ones. I realize I could pretty trivially filter this data using Django, but I could be dealing with hundreds of thousands of entries, something I'd rather not load into memory.